# Boostrap 4 - table tooltip position problem with one row and class table-sm

Tags: bootstrap-4

I found a problem with the placement of the tooltip in tables that have only one row and have the table-sm class

```
<!-- TOOLTIP POSITION OK -->
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>First</th>
           <th>Last</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span title="Foo tooltip">Foo</span> </td>
          <td><span title="Bar tooltip">Bar</span> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>

  <!-- TOOLTIP POSITION PROBLEM -->
  <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
         <thead>
            <tr>
             <th>First</th>
             <th>Last</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td><span title="Foo tooltip">Foo</span> </td>
             <td><span title="Bar tooltip">Bar</span> </td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).tooltip( { selector: '[title]', container : 'body' });
```

[Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/KDYOX1mAX0)

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [`boundary`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/#options) option to `viewport`

[**Bootply**](https://www.bootply.com/UdczGiad71)